# Special Drivers for Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, 21.10, mesa

I have Nvidia 1650 4GB graphics card. In 21.10 everything works fine. But I keep seeing articles about Mesa and it says they are for Nvidia.

I mainly do GIMP, Inkscape and Blender. Does adding any special drivers help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesa graphics drivers are built-in in Ubuntu, so you don't need to install them manually. Installing the recommended proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers if they aren't already installed with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot` will improve the performance of GIMP, Inkscape and Blender.

To show the proprietary graphics driver that is currently in use search for "Additional Drivers" in the Dash and click its icon to open it. You can also find the same information and more such as the current temperature of the graphics card in the NVIDIA X Server Settings app if it is installed.

Comment: How do we know the status of the proprietary driver? Thanks.

Comment: @user227495 I replied to your comment by editing my answer.